# How to [AllowHtml] but deny any scripts?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, unobtrusive-validation

In asp.net mvc to post any html i need to set `[AllowHtml]` on property and `Validate(input)` on controller, but how allowing post html **deny** to post any scripts?

Answer (score 2):

You could look at using [Microsoft Anti-Cross Site Scripting Library V4.0](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5242) to sanitize the input